# remove contiguous subarray to leave the average minimum

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This problem appeared in some regional contest for ICPC.

Given n numbers, you have to remove numbers between i to j such that remaining numbers have least average. You can't remove first and last numbers.

2 <= n <= 10^5

We had a discussion about it, and I am still not able to understand it. Some how this problem can be converted to finding contiguous subarray with maximum sum and then it was solved with binary search in O(nlog n).

I couldn't catch that solution while discussion and now after thinking a lot I am not able to understand that solution.

Link to the original problem in case it's not clear: http://programmingteam.cc.gatech.edu/contest/Mercer14/problems/6.pdf

Comment: Contiguous subarray with maximum sum can't be correct, as all numbers need to be not negative, at least that's my impression from the grades in your link. Thus, maximum sum would just always be alle elements except first an last. Maybe it would be possible to utilize partial averages.

Comment: The solution is something to do with contiguous sub-array with maximum average - that minimizes the remainder as required.  I couldn't find a chopping solution which wasn't fooled by local minima - that a larger slice would get smaller average, but if you increased it a bit more, it would have a larger average.

Comment: I think that if you add an element to the sub-array which makes it's average less than the global average, that would be wrong.  Although I see a sequence (with average = 0) such as {...,-1,-1,1,-1,0,10,10,-1-1,...} being such that adding {1}, {1,-1}, would be wrong, but from the other side {10}, {10,10}, {0,10,10},{-1,0,10,10}, {1,-1,0,10,10} would make sense, as the right-to-left fill is always above the total-average.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I think might work:

- Compute the partial average from left for all elements, with and updating average, this can be done in O(N): a_L(i) = (a_L(i-1)*(i-1) + a_L(i))/i
- Do the same for the partial averages from the right: a_R(i) = (a_R(i+1)*(N-i) + a_R(i))/(N-i+1)
- Find the minimum in of both lists.
- If the minimum is in the left partial averages (a_L), look for the minimum right to it in the a_R and the other way around if the minimum is found in a_R.

All parts take O(N). Thus, this would result in an O(N) algorithm. Though, it sounds a little bit simple and I might be missing something.

*Edit*: The original answer stopped in the middle for both lists, which is insufficient on second thought.

Actually, if the minima overlap, I believe, there is no interval to cut out. Here is a little Python implementation of the algorithm:

```
grades = [5, 5, 1, 7, 8, 2]

N = len(grades)
glob_avg = float(sum(grades))/float(N)
print('total average: {0}'.format(glob_avg))

avg_L = grades[:]
avg_R = grades[:]

minL = 0
minR = N-1

for i in range(1,N):
  avg_L[i] = float(avg_L[i-1]*i + grades[i])/float(i+1)
  if avg_L[i] <= avg_L[minL]:
    minL = i
  avg_R[N-i-1] = float(avg_R[N-i]*i + grades[N-i-1])/float(i+1)
  if avg_R[N-i-1] <= avg_R[minR]:
    minR = N-i-1

opti_avg = glob_avg
if minL < minR:
  first = minL+1
  last = minR
  opti_avg = (avg_L[first-1]*first + avg_R[last]*(N-last)) / float(N + first - last)
  print('')
  print('Interval to cut: {0} - {1}'.format(first,last))
  for pre in grades[:first]:
    print('{0}'.format(pre))
  for cut in grades[first:last]:
    print('X {0} X'.format(cut))
  for post in grades[last:]:
    print('{0}'.format(post))

else:
  print('NO interval found that would reduce the avg!')

print('')
print('--------------------------------------')
print('minimal avg: {0:0.3f}'.format(opti_avg))
print('--------------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try checking each value above the global minimum, starting with largest.

You can add to left or right (whichever is largest), as long as the average is above the global average.

Keep a note of any minimums to remaining items.

```
For each item >= global average
   While( average( selected) > global average
      If average(un selected items) < best so far
         Best so far = selected range
      End
      Add to selection largest of left and right
   End while
End for
```

Only by finding sequences which are above the average will a minimum for unselected work.

Any item which has been considered as a list can be discounted

Had a go at implementing in Python :-

```
lst = [ -1, -1,1,-90,1,3,-1,-1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1, -1,-1];
```

First solution - look really at an exhausitve test - allow me to verify correctness.

```
lbound = 0
ubound = len( lst)

print( ubound );

# from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing

def Average( lst, lwr, upr, runAvg = 0, runCnt = 0 ):
    cnt = runCnt;
    avg = runAvg;
    for i in range( lwr, upr ):
        cnt = cnt + 1
        avg = float(avg) + (float(lst[i]) - avg)/cnt
    return (avg, cnt )

bestpos_l = 0
bestpos_u = 0
bestpos_avg = 0
best_cnt = 0
######################################################
# solution in O(N^2) - works always
for i in range( 1, len( lst ) - 1 ):
    for j in range( i+1, len(lst ) ):
        tpl = Average( lst, 0, i ) # get lower end
        res = Average( lst, j, len(lst), tpl[0], tpl[1] )
        if (best_cnt == 0 or
              (best_cnt < res[1] and res[0] == bestpos_avg ) or
               res[0] < bestpos_avg ):
            bestpos_l = i
            bestpos_u = j
            bestpos_avg = res[0]
            best_cnt = res[1]
            print( "better", i,j, res[0], res[1] )

print( "solution 1", bestpos_l, bestpos_u, bestpos_avg, best_cnt )
```

This came up with valid answers, but I hadn't appreciated, with the current data set, it doesn't really want the right hand side.

```
########################################################
# O(N)
#
# Try and minimize left/right sides.
#
# This doesn't work - it knows -90 is really good, but can't decide if to
# ignore -90 from the left, or the right, so does neither.
# 
lower = []
upper = []
lower_avg = 0
best_lower = lst[0]
lower_i = 0
best_upper = lst[-1]
upper_avg = 0
upper_i = len(lst) -1
cnt = 0

length = len(lst)
for i in range( 0, length ):
    cnt = cnt + 1
    lower_avg = float( lower_avg) + ( float(lst[i]) - lower_avg)/cnt
    upper_avg = float( upper_avg) + ( float(lst[-(i+1)]) - upper_avg)/cnt
    upper.append( upper_avg )
    lower.append( lower_avg )
    if lower_avg <= best_lower:
        best_lower = lower_avg
        lower_i = i
    if upper_avg <= best_upper:
        best_upper = upper_avg
        upper_i = (len(lst) - (i+1))
if( lower_i + 1 > upper_i ):
    sol2 = Average( lst,0, len(lst ))
else:
    sol_tmp = Average( lst,0, lower_i+1 )
    sol2 = Average( lst, upper_i, len(lst),sol_tmp[0],sol_tmp[1] )

print( "solution 2", lower_i + 1, upper_i, sol2[0],sol2[1] )
```

The third solution was what I was trying to explain.  My implementation is limited because :-

1. Couldn't find a good way of finding starting points.  I wanted to start from the biggest elements, as they are most likely to reduce the average, but haven't got a good way of finding them.
2. Wasn't sure about the stability of keeping running-averages.  Thought about removing items from the average by un-doing each numbers effect.  Wasn't sure how this affected precision.
3. Was fairly sure that any interval which has been checked, can't have a starting item.  That would limit further work, but unsure how best to implement such (keeping O(xx) to a minimum.

### Solution 3

```
#################################
## can we remove first / last? if so, this needs adjusting

def ChooseNext( lst, lwr, upr ):
    if lwr > 1 and upr < len(lst) -2:
       # both sides available.
       if lst[lwr-1] > lst[upr]:
          return -1
       else:
          return 1
    elif lwr > 1:
      return -1
    elif upr < len(lst) -2:
      return 1
   return 0


# Maximize average of data removed.
glbl_average = Average( lst, 0, len(lst) )
found = False
min_pos = 0
max_pos = 0
best_average = glbl_average[0]

for i in range(1, len(lst ) - 1):
    # ignore stuff below average.
    if lst[i]> glbl_average[0] or (found == False ):
        lwr = i
        upr = i+1
        cnt = 1 # number for average
        avg = lst[i]
        tmp = Average( lst, 0, lwr)
        lcl = Average( lst, upr, len(lst ), tmp[0], tmp[1] )
        if found == False or lcl[0] < best_average:
           best_average = lcl[0]
           min_pos = lwr
           max_pos = upr
           found = True

        # extend from interval (lwr,upr]
        choice = ChooseNext( lst, lwr, upr )
        while( choice != 0 ):
            if( choice == -1):
                new_lwr = lwr -1
                new_upr = upr
            else:
                new_lwr = lwr
                new_upr = upr + 1
            tmp = Average( lst, 0, new_lwr )
            lcl_best = Average( lst, new_upr, len(lst), tmp[0], tmp[1] )
            if( lcl_best[0] > glbl_average[0]):
                choice = 0
            else:
                lwr = new_lwr
                upr = new_upr
                if lcl_best[0] < best_average:
                   min_pos = lwr
                   max_pos = upr
                   best_average = lcl_best[0]
                choice = ChooseNext( lst, lwr, upr )
```

print( "solution 3", min_pos, max_pos, best_average )